# Default comparer when using OrderBy extension

Tags: c#, compare

Out of curiosity: What comparer is used when sorting a bunch of objects using the following extension method?

```
OrderBy(x=> x)
```

**Background:** I have to check wether two ISet< T > instances contain the same elements and considered to use the

```
bool setsEqual = MySet.SequenceEqual(OtherSet);
```

method. As the order of those elements contained in the sets are not defined and may differ, a SequenceEqual would fail in those cases where the internal order is not the same. So i would have to explictly define an order. As the order algo for itself is completely irrelevant as long as it´s stable, i just used an "Identity" lambda expression:

```
bool setsEqual = MySet.OrderBy(x => x).SequenceEqual(OtherSet.OrderBy(x => x);
```

But what does "Compare the objects themselves" mean to the code? As this OrderBy extension method is a generic one, there must be a default compare algo in place that is able to sort objects without knowing anything more about it, and that would mean a comparison for sorting had to be delegated to the type of the set elements itself. Is there an interface that the elements´ type would have to support, or is there a default comparer (may be comparing internal memory addresses of objects) in place?

Comment: `OrderBy` uses [`Comparer<TKey>.Default`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azhsac5f(v=vs.110).aspx), as you can see [here](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,cb26c46274356e0d,references)

Comment: `ISet<T>` contains a `SetEquals` method for testing equality with a sequence.

Comment: So, what would be the default order for TKey being a direct descendant of object, not implementing IComparable?

Comment: @Udontknow. There is no default order - the default comparer will throw an exception

Answer (score 1):

The method used the [`IComparable<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/4d7sx9hd%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)-or the [`IComparable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.icomparable(v=vs.110).aspx)-interface  depending on which of both are implemented. If none is implemented the order is arbitrary.

However you won´t need to order you instances before comparing the sets. Simply loop one set and check if all of its elements are contained in the other set. Or use this:

```
var areEqual = firstSet.All(x => secondSet.Contains(x)) && secondSet.All(x => firstSet.Contains(x));
```

Or even simpler:

```
var areEqual = !firstSet.Except(secondSet).Any() && !secondSet.Except(firstSet).Any();
```

Both ways perform much faster than your appraoch as the iteration of elements stops when the first element is found that does not fit. Using `OrderBy` you´d loop all elements, regardless if there was already a mismatch.

Comment: Didn't you mean `var areEqual = !firstSet.Except(secondSet).Any() && !secondSet.Except(firstSet).Any();`

Comment: For my specific case, Lee already pointed out that there is the method "SetEquals", but what does "Otherwise the order is arbitrary" mean? "Arbitrary" in the sense of "indeterministic"? Same input -> different results possible?

Comment: Well, it won´t change from one call to another one I guess. However there´s no attribute on which ordering is applied whereby you may call it undeterministic. How should your program decide how to sort a list of cars for example if you don´t provide this information?

Comment: At the very least, all cars are objects. As mentioned in the question, i could think of a default comparer that just compares the pointers of these objects. Another idea could be to compare via object.GetHashCode(). Both variants would produce a stable "deterministic" order (assuming GetHashCode is properly implemented, that is).

Comment: If you can implement `GetHashCode` - meaning you have access to the classes and can modfy them - why don´t you simply implement the interface appropriately. The `GetHashCode`-method is not designed for this purpose. However I assume if no comparer is set the `OrderBy`statement WILL use any deterministic information but you can´t say which one.

Answer (score 1):

**To answer the question of sorting:** sorting uses `IComparable<T>` or [`IComperable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icomparable.compareto(v=vs.110).aspx) if that isn't implemented.  The `IComperable` interfaces force you to implement a `int CompareTo(object)` method (or `int CompareTo(T)` method if you used the typed version).

The order of your elements is determined by the sign of the int.  The value returned is interpreted as follows:

- `0`: the two objects are equivalent (i.e. the same)
- `-1`: the compared object *precedes* this object (i.e. comes before this object)
- `1`: the compared object *follows* this object (i.e. comes after this object)

The actual value is ignored, the sign is all that matters.  If you implement your own `IComparable` interface, you have to choose the semantics for sort order.

Many objects already implement `IComparable` already, like all your numbers, strings, etc.  You'll need to implement it explicitly if you need to sort objects you've created yourself.  It's not a bad practice if you intend those objects to be displayed in a list on screen at all.

**As to your specific case**, where you just need to determine if a set and another `IEnumerable` are equivalent, then you would use the [`ISet<T>.SetEquals(IEnumerable<T>)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd412096(v=vs.110).aspx) method which is implemented in the standard library set implementations.  Sets, by definition, only guarantee the values are unique, so as long as the number of elements are the same, you only need to detect that all the elements in one `IEnumerable` can be found in the set.

Answer (score 0):

Unlike for equality, there's no 'default' comparer for objects in general.
It seems that `Comparer<TKey>.Default` always returns a comparer, for any type `TKey`. If no sensible comparison method can be determined, you get an exception, but only once the comparer is used.

> At least one object must implement IComparable.